# Postgres sql table return statement

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-migration

I got a question related to an translation from SQL Server to Postgres.

I got an table return statement and I don't know how to translate this to Postgres.

my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLastUpdatedFluidTreated](@InjectionPoint_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)  
RETURNS @Return TABLE (
    [RT_FluidTreated_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CL_FluidTreatedType_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [Last_Updated_Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [NewOrModified] [bit] NULL,
    [Origin_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [IsNew] [bit] NULL
    )
AS   
BEGIN  
    

    INSERT INTO @Return
    Select Top 1
        x1.[RT_FluidTreated_ID],
        x1.[CL_FluidTreatedType_ID],
        x1.[Timestamp],
        x1.[Last_Updated_Time],
        x1.[NewOrModified],
        x1.[Origin_ID],
        x1.[IsNew]
    from RT_FluidTreated x1
    WHERE x1.RE_InjectionPoint_ID = @InjectionPoint_ID
    Order by x1.[Last_Updated_Time] desc
    RETURN;
END
```

this code above is on sql server.
Can someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple set-returning function is what you are looking for:

```
create function getlastupdatedfluidtreated(p_injectionpoint_id uuid)  
  returns table (
      rt_fluidtreated_id uuid not null,
      cl_fluidtreatedtype_id uuid not null,
      timestamp timestamp null,
      last_updated_time timestamp null,
      newormodified boolean null,
      origin_id uuid null,
      isnew boolean null)
as   
$$
  select
      x1.rt_fluidtreated_id,
      x1.cl_fluidtreatedtype_id,
      x1.timestamp,
      x1.last_updated_time,
      x1.newormodified,
      x1.origin_id,
      x1.isnew
  from rt_fluidtreated x1
  where x1.re_injectionpoint_id = p_injectionpoint_id
  order by x1.last_updated_time desc
  limit 1 --<< replaces TOP 1
$$
language sql;
```

I adjusted the used data types to the most reasonable types in Postgres. You will need to adjust that to the actual types you have used in your table `rt_fluidtreated`